# django event attendee list / user events list foreign key backward search chain

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am making something like a party planner.
I want users to be able to confirm their attendance, with the option of canceling later.
I want to display a list of attendees on the event page, and a list of events confirmed to be attended on each users profile page.
I also want to use attendance to opt in to update emails about those events.

---

I have a **Model** for the Event:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_of = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,)
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):

        return self.title
```

and a **Model** for Attendance - to link Users as attendees to Events:

```
class Attendance(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='event')
    attendee = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='attendee')
    is_attending = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s - %s" % (self.event, self.attendee)
```

---

The **View** for the Event is

```
@login_required
def event(request, event_id):
    event = get_object_or_404(Event, id=event_id)
    shopping_list = event.item_set.order_by('date_added')
    form = VSLForm()
    attendee_list = event.event.all()
    print("\n\n\n\n" + str(attendee_list) + "\n\n\n\n")

    context = {'event': event, 'shopping_list': shopping_list, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'VSL/event.html', context)
```

I have a **View** for a button to confirm attendance

```
@login_required
def is_attending(request, event_id):
    """set user as attending an event."""
    event = get_object_or_404(Event, id=event_id)
    attendance = Attendance(
        attendee = request.user, 
        event = event,
        is_attending = True
        )
    attendance.save()
    return redirect('VSL:events')
```

and a **View** for a button to cancel attendance

```
@login_required
def not_attending(request, event_id):
    """set user as NOT attending an event."""
    event = get_object_or_404(Event, id=event_id)
    attendance = Attendance.objects.get(
        attendee = request.user, 
        event = event,
        is_attending = True
        )
    attendance.delete()
    return redirect('VSL:events')
```

---

There will be many events and many users, and not everyone will be going to everything.

The line `attendee_list = event.event.all()` in the event view gives a QuerySet e.g.`<Queryset [<Attendance: Christmas - Escatologist>, <Attendance: Christmas - Determinist>]>`

When what I want is just the *Escatologist* and *Determinist* bit.

What I do not know is how to usefully use that information to

- create a list of user attending each event in the event template
- create a list of events confirmed as attending in the users profile template
- send update emails only to attendees of events (not all active users)

Is having an attendance model even the right way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should *really* fix your nomenclature. The `related_name` is the name of the relation in reverse, so this is typically *not* `event` in case of an `Event`, but `attendants`:

```
class Attendance(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='attedants')
    attendee = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='attending')
    is_attending = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s - %s" % (self.event, self.attendee)
```

We can then write queries to obtain the information:

1. create a list of user attending each event in the event template

for a list `events` of `Event`s, we can check if a user is attending all these events with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

User.objects.filter(
    attending__event__in=events,
    attending__is_attending=True
).annotate(
    cattendance=Count('attending')
).filter(
    cattendance__gte=len(events)
)
```

2. create a list of events confirmed as attending in the users profile template

In that case we can obtain the events with:

```
Event.objects.filter(attendants__attendee=my_user, attendants__is_attending=True)
```

So here we filter the `Event`s such that one of the related `Attendance` has `my_user` as `attendee` and for that `Attendance`, `is_attending` is set to `True`.

3. send update emails only to attendees of events (not all active users)

We can obtain the `User`s that are attending with a similar query:

```
User.objects.filter(attending__event=my_event, attending__is_attending=True)
```

So here we obtain all the `User`s that have said they will attend `my_event`.

Comment: Thanks ever so much @willem-van-onsem, that has been a great help.